# Tri-Gate effect

Tags: yu-gi-oh

So here is one I wish to know:

I use Tri-Gate second effect, which allows me to target and banish one card on the field. Then I link that with another monster to bring out another link. Tri-Gate would be in the graveyard but then I use transcodes effect (1 of the 3 co-links) to bring it back from the graveyard.

Can I use the second effect again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youtuber dzeeff recently did a video on this about hard/soft once-per-turn effects.

In the case you bring up, Trigate has a soft once-per-turn effect. This means that specific card instance if you will has that restriction. If you bring that same card out again in another instance that restriction is gone and you can use it again.

A hard once-per-turn effect however, restricts all copies and instances of the monster/spell/trap. Even if you go out your way to bring out another copy of that monster, the effect will still not be triggered.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TaDmB-IxSV4

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

The rule with once per turn effects is as follows:

If the cards simply says, "once per turn you can..." or any variation on this. It basically means once per turn, per card. If the monster is removed from the field and summoned again, this state resets because it no longer counts as the same card.

On the other hand if the cards states something along the lines of "you can only use this effect of "Monster Name" once per turn", then the effect can only be used once per turn for any card with that name. That includes any other physical copies of that monster you would summon.